# Zooming frame graphics in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, ios, flash-cs5

I am developing a Flash CS5 iOS app. On one of the frames I am drawing a good many rectangles in a particular pattern.  I would like to use two-finger zoom and gestures to zoom into these rectangles on the frame but keep the general pattern of these rectangles the same.  Also once zoomed in, the user will need to pan around the enlarged graphics.

I know I could create an event handler that when I zoom in it adds width and height to each of the rectangles but then I have to worry about increasing the X and Y positions of each of the rectangles so I keep the same distance between each one and so forth.

I there an easier way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're drawing the rectangles as vectors, you should be able to use the scale the property I think, otherwise you might need to redraw the bitmap rectangles based on the new scale.

To use the Zoom Gesture you must first set the inputMode to touch:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
```

and you'll need to listen to [TransformGestureEvent.ZOOM](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TransformGestureEvent.html#GESTURE_ZOOM) and use the event's scaleX,scaleY:

```
yourRectangles.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.ZOOM,onZoom);

function onZoom(event:TransformGestureEvent):void{
trace(event.scaleX,event.scaleY);
}
```

HTH